# Android spinner dont draw selected item

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner with three items in it

```
<string-array name="menuitems">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
</string-array>
```

Then I set up my spinner like this

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
         R.array.menuitems,  R.layout.spinnerstyle);

 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinnerdropdownstyle);

 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The spinner displays like this

### One

One

Two

Three

My problem is for this spinner I don't want to display the selected item I want this

### One

Two

Three

And obviously if two were selected only one and three would appear in the dropdown. I did search for this but couldn't figure out a way to get that affect I tried changing the menuitems array on selection but if I removed the item from there it wouldn't draw it in the selection. I assume there is a fairly easy way to get this affect.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom [`SpinnerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) which returns the items from the menu excluding the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the promt in the xml to "One" like this:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerTest"  
 android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
 android:prompt="@string/SelectOne"
 android:layout_marginRight="30px"
 android:layout_height="35px" 
/>
```

Then you should override the onItemClick methode and set the text of your variable in
"On nothing selected".