# Android Spinner: is there absolutely no neat way to avoid displaying the selected item twice?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-spinner

I searched for this everywhere, the behavior I'm trying to implement is very simple, This is actually a duplicate of a question asked more than 2 years ago but with no real answer ([Android spinner dont draw selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878533/android-spinner-dont-draw-selected-item))

Basically, I have a spinner that acts like a drop down list containing 3 items x,y,z. So when I select x, I should only see y and z in the list(plus the x selected on top), instead I get that x plus x,y,z.

Why is this a very bad design from a user perspective? because when the user clicks the spinner, the view looks like this (x,y,z are images btw :) ) :

x

x

y

z

The only fix I thought of is to check on every select event and remove the selected from the list of items, which is far from a neat solution, especially that I need to optimize performance in my app.

Any ideas?

Comment: and the removal kills performance?

Comment: I just looked at a spinner in the app I'm currently working on. It looks like the spinner popup view displays on top of (over) the currently selected item. So basically, even if there are two x's, the first x is hidden, so only the list contents are shown. That seems fine to me. Is that not how yours works?

Comment: Thanks @hungryghost, but there are 2 modes for the spinner: popup or DDL (drop down list). Looks like you're using the popup, where it makes sense to have two x's of course. But the DDL mode kinda looks like the regular DDL you'd see at a desktop app or an html page.

Comment: @Elltz, I haven't tried it but I'm afraid that it might affect performance which is absolutely unacceptable in my app, plus I've seen in other posts people trying and failing at it... obviously that's what I'll try if I don't find any 'chic' solution :)

Answer (score 0):

After I spent more than four hours trying to solve that problem in every possible way I realized that probably someone had passed for the same as me and build a library to solve that.

Thankfully I was right and I found that awesome library: https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner

It builds an spinner above an AutocompleteTextView, kind hacky, but works a lot better than the android spinner.

With this library, you can build a custom adapter and setVisibility(View.GONE) in the view that you don't want to show in the dropdown. For some bizarre reason, setVisibility(View.GONE) and getLayoutParams().height = 0 don't hide the item in the spinner dropdown.

Hope it solves your problem, solved mine :)

Comment: Thanks for that :) I will give it a try by next week and update